# Can't change an Image from a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Im trying to change an image when a list item in listview is clicked.  This is what ppl say to use but it doesn't work.  the log file says that there is a null pointer exception at the setimageresource line.  Any ideas?

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        if(arg2 == 0){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lighton);
        }
            else

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lightoff);
    }
});
```

**Logcat**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.NullPointerException
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at com.Sonny.HCIProject.LightSetting$1.onItemClick(LightSetting.java:42)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:283)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3132)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1620)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 03:54:48.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-20 03:54:48.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
03-20 03:54:48.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
03-20 03:54:48.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the Drawable folder has only the picture files

Comment: put your full logcat....

Comment: And show us your drawable resource folder structure if possible.

Comment: I think your not getting your imageview id properly

Answer (score 0):

What is image? Where is it? Is it initialized? Please, more listing.

Maybe you should try

```
YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this.image
```

Or maybe not

Comment: image is an imageView that is set to the view id

Comment: here is the code 'code' ImageView image;  image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.lighton);

Answer (score 0):

If image is an item in the list view,then you have to do like this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
             ImageView img=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.image);
             img.setImageDrawable(getResourses().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable1));
    }
});
```

If its not an item in the listview, your code should work if you have instantiated

Comment: I have instantiated the imageview gave it the id of the imageview in the xml and still nothing

Comment: image is an item in list view? or outside list view?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace says the problem is on line 42.  If you are 100% sure this is line 42,

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lighton);
```

then OK. If it's not, please post line 42 as a comment.

SO, assuming that is line 42,

Either

1. Check your imports at the top-- make sure it is `import my.project.R;` and not `import android.R;`
2. `image` is null.  Do you instantiate it?

Basically, either what you are trying to set or where you are trying to set it is null.  One or the other, or if you are unlucky, both.

Comment: Ok so I've imported my project like you said and nothing, also i've instantiated a imageview for the image like so lightOn = new ImageView(LightSetting.this);
 lightOn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lightimage);  then in the onclick method i still get teh null exceptio error at this same place     lightOn.setImageResource(R.drawable.lighton);
I'm completely stumped